# Automatically Create LocalDB with EF7

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework-core, localdb

I'm using `EF7` in a `WebForms` environment, with a back end database of `LocalDB`.

Ideally what I want to do is on each application run, automatically apply any migrations as needed to upgrade the current DB to the latest version (easy enough, I can call `context.Database.Migrate()` ).

However if the DB doesn't already exist (as in the raw mdf file) it doesn't get crated. This is normally fixed ( I believe by calling `context.Database.EnsureCreated()` ) however that makes the database, with all the latest schema (and does not allow EF Migration updating in the future).

Any suggestions on how to allow the app to auto create the db whilst still allowing future migrations?

Comment: I think migrate should also create the database for you!?

Comment: Di you see this article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt614250.aspx ? They explain why there is no more magic database Initialization.